# iOS 13 Transparent Toolbar

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, ios13, ios14

I'm trying to recreate the iOS13 Reminders toolbar appearance but am struggling with the translucent transition.

If I change the backgroundImage and shadowImage to an empty image I can recreate the transparent toolbar but when the user scrolls behind the toolbar I don't get the translucent effect.

Does anyone know how to switch from the transparent to the translucent toolbar when the user scrolls behind it? :)

[iOS13 Reminders app demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk8Sk.gif)

Comment: Use the iOS 13 appearance classes?

Comment: I can use the iOS 13 appearance classes but can't get the transition to work, when the user scrolls behind the tabbar the tabbar should become translucent with a border. I've added an .gif at the link above that explains it better than I can.